# Revisions not saving

Tags: versioning, revisions

All my channels are set to save revisions, but only some channels do and some do not. I cannot figure out the reason. I should admit that i updated the ee_channels table to set the max_revisions from 10 to 100 to save time, but i doubt that could have done anything.

Anyone have any idea what else could be causing this?

EE v2.9.3

Comment: Update: this only happens on certain entries, new entries created the revisions work, old entries it does not.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i figured it out. I didn't realize at first but the data was migrated, and while the channel was a Y for revisions, the entries were not.